# What is the Drop Rate for Magic Items by Act?

Tags: diablo-iii

Blizzard's Patch notes sometimes provide data on the drop rate for an item level range in a specific Act/Difficulty.

For example, the [1.0.3 notes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6457499/Patch_103_Now_Available-6_19_2012#blog) provided this information :

```
High-end items (items level 61-63) will now drop in all Acts of Inferno and Acts III and IV of Hell difficulty
The new approximate drop rates are as follows:
Hell - Act III and Act IV
iLvl 61: 9%
iLvl 62: 1.9%
iLvl 63: 0%
```

I'd like to know exactly this information, but for items from 1 to 63, and all Acts/Difficulties. I find myself trying to decide between playing in an Act that is really hard for my character, or going back to something easier to grind for gear. It would help to know if the gear from previous acts is likely to help me, or if I would just be getting items too low to use.

Comment: Ha! I was just looking for this info the other day here and elsewhere. I've seen posts/threads on things before but nothing concrete. I did read on reddit.com/r/diablo that Blizzard might be releasing some more stats on item drops down the road.

Comment: This information hasn't been released by Blizzard with the exception of the information in the patch notes for patch 1.0.3

Comment: @ickleislands That's unfortunate; I would love to have official data. Still, if enough people kept track, you could estimate the drop rates pretty well. There were/are plenty of such sites for WoW.

Comment: @Drew I agree, to reliably track such things though would probably require addons to reduce the 'user error' component of such data gathering. Unfortunately Diablo 3 does not support addons otherwise I imagine such a thing would have been created already.

Comment: I'd say focus on the easier act. While the tougher act may yield a slightly better chance at higher iLevels, it will typically take a greater amount of time to farm, and result in less items overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Official Brady Games Diablo III guide says this about the loot system.

> "If a monster drops loot, the quality of the item(s) dropped is most affected by the monster's level. If the loot bursts from an environmental object like a chest or barrel or pile of bones, the type/quality of items is most affected by where you're at in the game.
>
> Other factors can come into play, as well. The fact is, Diablo III monsters can drop a wide range of loot items, but the odds of a low-level monster dropping a high-quality item are extremely small. So overall, it works just as you'd expect: The higher a monster's level, the better chance that it drops good loot after you slay the beast."

It also goes on to say;

> "Again, there are ranges of quality for both the base item *and* for any affixed special properties. As we said, the primary variable that determines the quality of a slain monster's loot drop is the monster's level----the higher the monster level, the more the odds are weighted in favor of it dropping a higher quality base item, and the better chance that the game will also attach higher quality enhancements (or "affixes") to that base item.
>
> These item/affix ranges are divided into "tiers" that correspond to the monster levels. If the monster is a low-level creature, chances are that any gear it drops will be selected from the lower tiers of items, and enhancements assigned (if any) will be from lower-tier affixes. Thus, each monster is said to have a "treasure tier" based on its level----the game tends to drop random items selected from item/affix tiers that correspond to the monster's level."

This is why the patch notes you quoted say "The new ***approximate*** drop rates are as follows" since drops from mobs are not based on act but monster level.

When I have some time I'll compile a list of the level ranges for each act/difficulty since the guide does have a complete list of the bestiary complete with monster levels.

To be honest I think you're over thinking it a bit. If you're level 60 then you should be farming the highest act you can reasonably do no lower than act 3 Hell mode and if you're lower than level 60 then farm the highest act you can farm efficiently. Farming one act back from whatever act is giving you trouble will give you a chance at gear you can use.

*edit*

- Act 1 has ilvl 61 mobs
- Act 2 has ilvl 62 mobs
- Acts 3 & 4 have ilvl 63 mobs

There are some higher (and lower in act 2) level mobs in both acts 1 & 2 but not many. Act 1 has one ilvl 63 (spiderlings) for instance.

Comment: Be careful of copyright violations when copying info from the guide.  Try to paraphrase it into your own words.

Comment: @bwarner Thanks, I was a bit concerned that I might be quoting too much of the text but I do believe this falls within the fair use doctrine. I will try to paraphrase more in the future though.